# How to bring the item's detail to another page when the item was clicked using PHP?

Tags: php, sql, web

I'm working on a site that consists of clickable image products. Every product has its own name, price and description that comes from the database but I'm not really sure about how can I do this by clicking the product will bring its product name, price and description to another page? Here's an illustrative example of what I mean:
[image]

Here's what I did trying to make it appear to another page:

```
<div class="product-100" id=<?PHP echo("'".$ItemID."'"); ?>>
<?PHP echo "<a href='content pages/a-2.php?ItemID=$ItemID' >"; ?>
<span class="overlay">
    <p><?PHP echo($ItemName); ?><br>
    <?PHP echo($ItemPrice);?><br>
    <?PHP echo($ItemDesc);?></p>
</span>
</a>
```

And here's what the other page I did with:

```
$ItemID = $_GET['ItemID'];
$viewproducts = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Items WHERE ItemID = '".ItemID."'";
```

Of course, ItemID of the product is the only one that shows to the other page.

Comment: `.ItemID.` is being treated as a constant. Put the `$` in there `'".$ItemID."'`. Checking for errors would have thrown "undefined constant ItemID..." - Or, was that a typo?

Comment: _Never_ try handing over details about an action item from one page to another. Always re-read those details from a save point, which is your database. Everyone with the most basic knowledge about how the web works can freely change details like price and the like from page to page... Instead only handle an identifier, because that is the only information you really have on the client side: _that_ object was clicked.

Comment: Wondering if anyone's going to *sink their teeth* into what I said; *probably, most likely.*

Comment: @Fred-ii- oh my god! after a long days of working on this, it finally worked! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: You're welcome. Would you like me to post that as an answer so we can close 'er up?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yup! thank you guys and fred for the help! I can't express any other more happiness!

Comment: Watch out! You should be aware of mysql injections.
Consider using the `mysqli_real_escape_string` function.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Comment to answer, to close 'er up:*

`.ItemID.` is being treated as a [**constant**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php).

Put the `$` in there `'".$ItemID."'`.

Checking for errors would have thrown "undefined constant ItemID..."

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php